# flapjack plugin installation with logstash

Tags: rubygems

I have output plugin for flapjack in path vendor\local_gems. Even if when i am trying to list all the gems, i am not able to see the local flapjack gem. After installation of plugin, the below entries are there in Gemfile.

`gem "logstash-output-flapjack", "0.1.5", :path => "vendor/local_gems/0472ffe3/logstash-output-flapjack-0.1.5"`

But the folder `vendor/local_gems/0472ffe3/logstash-output-flapjack-0.1.5` is empty. I am not getting any gem file inside the above package. I have used the below commands to install the output plugin.

`gem build logstash-output-flapjack.gemspec
bin/plugin install logstash-output-flapjack-0.1.5.gem`

So when I am trying to start the logstash by using below command
`bin/logstash -f logstash-filter.conf`

I am getting the message that its not able to find the output block of flapjack. It means logstash is not able to locate the plugin for flapjack.

Comment: Hi Yash, Now its working. Added the below line s.files = Dir[ 'lib/logstash/outputs/*.rb', 'spec/**/*.rb'] in logstash-output-flapjack.gemspec file. Thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question and help others